# How to backup the partition table of a mmcblk disk

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt, partition-copy

I've been using parted-magic to backup my computers' system disks for a while.

So far I've been using either sfdisk or sgdisk for saving the partition table; most of the time, if sfdisk fail I'm using sgdisk and everything works, but I got a new notebook with a 32 GB flash storage (seen as /dev/mmcblk0) and I cannot really understand what is going on.

As you can see in the screen capture bellow, sfdisk did work, but the label of the device is "GPT"... So I tried using sgdisk, which ended up in a lot of "Error 38 when determining sector size"

[image: sfdisk vs sgdisk]

I thought that because the "disk" was small, they had used an "old style" MBR partition table, but after some googling I tried the command "gdisk -l" and it says it does have a GPT partition table.

[image: gdisk -l]

To make things a little more weird, now "sgdisk --backup" seems to work without any error...

So my questions are:

- What is the best way to determine the type of partition table of a new computer (and to backup/restore it)?
- Why is there no longer "error 38" messages with sgdisk? (did I accidentally modify something on the partition?)
- How can I check that a sgdisk backup file is correct? (with sfdisk, this was an ascii file so you could just look into it, but it doesn't seems to work with sgdisk)
- Bonus: What is the difference between sgdisk and gdisk?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I was able to partially answer the questions, so here are my findings:

- What is the best way to determine the type of partition table of a new computer (and to backup/restore it)?

  `gdisk -l device_name` seems to be the way to go to find out which partition table is used.

  Once you get this, if you have a GPT you backup it with `sgdisk --backup=filename`, if you don't you backup it with `sfdisk -d device_name> filename`
- How can I check that a sgdisk backup file is correct? (with sfdisk, this was an ascii file so you could just look into it, but it doesn't seems to work with sgdisk)

  I think you should be able to load it into gdisk using the recovery menu command `l` (lowercase L) and then print it with command `p`. It should be safe as long as you don't use the `w` command to write back to the device the new GPT.

  To make things easier, I added the following line to my backup script so I can access important information about the GPT: `gdisk -l device_name >filename 2>&1`. That's a different filename that the one I used with `sgdisk --backup` of course.
- Bonus: What is the difference between sgdisk and gdisk?

  `sgdisk` is the scriptable version of `gdisk`. The most notable difference is that `sgdisk` will perform dangerous operations without asking for any confirmation... so be careful when using it.

I still don't know why the "error 38" messages disappeared so feel free to add an answer for that, and to confirm that what I answered is right... or wrong.